# Fetching upstream from branch other than master

Tags: git, github, fork, clone, fetch

I have forked a github repo and cloned it locally. But I need to fetch the upstream from the forked repo's `develop` branch, not the `master` branch.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

I appear to have resolved it. Here are the commands executed for fetching upstream from a branch other than master:

`git checkout master`
`git fetch upstream`
`git merge upstream/develop`
`git checkout <feature_branch>`
`git merge master`
resolve conflicts, ensure specs still pass
`git push origin <feature_branch>`

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer and mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Create and switch to a matching local `develop` branch

   ```
   git checkout -b develop
   ```
2. Pull your upstream changes to `develop`

   ```
   git pull origin develop
   ```
3. Merge with `master`

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge develop
   ```

Comment: I thought it was git checkout -b instead of -d

Comment: I did that but it didn't do anything  \
git branch --track develop upstream/develop  \
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from upstream.  \
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:usemusic Ben$ git branch  \
  develop  \
  featuredartists  \
* master

Comment: From my local develop branch, I've tried "git fetch upstream develop" and it doesn't pull anything. also tried "git pull upstream develop" and still nothing.

Comment: @uDaY the origin is my forked remote repo. I need to pull from the repo i forked from: upstream/develop.

Comment: @BenjaminDunphy what do you get if you type `git remote -v`

Comment: @uDaY I get fetch and push for both origin and upstream. Thanks for your assistance -- see my updated question as I have resolved the issue.